# Python oursql treating a string variable as a char array

Tags: python, parameters, oursql

Forgive my ignorance as I am new to oursql.  I'm simply trying to pass a parameter to a statement:

cursor.execute("select blah from blah_table where blah_field = ?", blah_variable)

this treated whatever is inside the blah_variable as a char array so if I pass "hello" it will throw a ProgrammingError telling me that 1 parameter was expected but 5 was given.

I've tried looking through the docs but their examples are not using variables.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cursor.execute()` call expects a `params` argument that is iterable. [The documentation only hints at it](http://pythonhosted.org/oursql/api.html#oursql.Cursor.execute), but the code actually unpacks the argument and passes it to another function:

```
# from oursqlx/cursor.pyx:121
# in Cursor.execute()
        else:
            stmt.execute(*params)
```

You would need to phrase your call like:

```
cursor.execute("select blah from blah_table where blah_field = ?", [blah_variable]) # brackets!
```

Comment: Awesome guys thanks!  Ian was just a bit faster but since you showed the source I'm gonna accept this answer

Answer (score 1):

IT is expecting a sequence of parameters. Use:

`[blah_variable]`